# REGEX Passing parameter to wordpress page with shortcode with pretty urls

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Currently, I am using this page

http://irvinesprings.com/springs-manufacturer/

which has a shortcode which can read parameters passed using GET.

by adding

http://irvinesprings.com/springs-manufacturer/?spring=Tension&area=Irvine

It will read the get variable and generate some extra content and again it will change depending on the area.

Editing the rewrite rules aren't a problem as I've found a solution to adding the rules.

The existing rule for turning the page name into the correct rewrite rule 
 for /springs-manufacturer/

```
(.?.+?)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$
```

which rewrites to

```
index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
```

Ideally, I would like to have 
/springs-manufacturer/spring/Tension/area/Irvine

which would have a rewritten URL of something like

```
/spring/(.*)/area/(.*) ?spring=$1&area=$2
```

I just can't for the life of me combine these two rules effectively to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Regex Pattern

```
(springs-manufacturer)/spring/(.*)/area/(.*)$
```

Match

```
index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&spring=$matches[2]&area=$matches[3]
```